Physical interpretation of selection rules for different multipole orders
While going through this resource, I came across the following statement:

The interaction $eE(0, t) · x$
in (2.8) describes the coupling of the external field to the electric dipole moment $d = ex$ of
the electron with respect to the origin – hence the term dipole approximation.

I struggle with this physical interpretation because, according to my understanding, dipole moment is something that is defined for a pair of charges instead of a single charge. However, the referred notes talk about dipole moment of an electron with respect to the origin. My intuition is that the presence of a nucleus is implicit in the form of the electron's wave function since this creates the potential that defines these wave functions. However, this does not follow the conventional definition of electric dipoles and that is why I am still doubtful about my interpretation.
I understand the next multipole order as follows: an electron is a charged particle with a spin, hence a magnetic moment, which is what the field would address during magnetic dipole coupling.
However, extending this idea to electric quadrupole and magnetic quadrupole also becomes difficult for me. I understand that they are primarily defined by the mathematical expressions of the matrix elements in question, but since a lot of sources also talk in terms of field couplings to actual physical quantities, I am hoping to understand what those quantities mean.
Are these physical interpretations rigorous? If so, could someone please explain in each case which property of the atom/electron is the external field coupling to?

One way to understand dipole or multipole fields are through the multipolar expansion. The idea is simple: Consider that you have a distribution of charges in space. Of course it produces some potential $V$. The multipolar expansion tells me that I can expand it and write
$$
V = {Q_{tot}\over r} + {\mathbf P\cdot \mathbf r\over r^3} + {\mathbf r \cdot \mathbf Q\cdot \mathbf r\over r^5} +\dots
$$
Where $Q$ is the total charge distributed, $\mathbf P$ is the electric dipole moment, $\mathbf Q$ is the electric quadrupole moment, etc. Now, look that if what we have is a point charge, only the first term remains, nothing else.
However, consider that we have a point charge displaced by $\mathbf s$ of the origin. The potential of this charge at a point $\mathbf r$ will be
$$
V = {Q\over |\mathbf r - \mathbf s|}.
$$
By approximation, we could write
$$
V = {Q\over \sqrt{ r^2 + s^2 - 2\mathbf r\cdot\mathbf s}} = {Q\over r \sqrt{1 + (\frac sr)^2 - 2{\mathbf s\cdot \mathbf r\over r^2}}} = \frac Qr\left ( 1 - {\mathbf r\cdot \mathbf s\over r^2} + \mathcal O\left({1\over r^2}\right)\right)
$$
The first term is the monopole term of the multipolar expansion. The second term is a dipole correction that increases linearly with the displacement $|\mathbf s|$. We could in principle include other correction terms, that will account as multipolar terms.

So multipole fields are not only related to the presence of multiple charges. They are corrections for the monopole field, and they could appear in any situation where the potential is not exactly the monopole one (first term).
